# C# Action which encapsulates a method with signature void SomeFunc(class arg)

Tags: c#, delegates, action

It exist something like Action but which can encapsulate method with signature:

```
void SomeFunc(IDictionary<string,class>), I try solve this:

    private void RefreshContactList()
    {
       var freshFriends = Service.GetAllFriends(Account);

        new System.Action(RefreshContactsData(freshFriends)).OnUIThread();
    }

    private void RefreshContactsData(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, UserInfo>> freshFriends)
    {
          //...
    }
```

Comment: Im guessing English is not your first language, but could you try to explain the question a little more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use [generic Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx). You can write then:

```
Action<IDictionary> myAction; //with one parameter
Action<IDictionary, int> myAction2; //with two parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Your code tries to create a delegate incorrectly - you are passing in the return value of a method invocation:

```
new System.Action(RefreshContactsData(freshFriends))
```

instead of the method itself:

```
new System.Action(RefreshContactsData)
```

However, there would be no point in creating a delegate only to call it immediately - you could just as easily call the method directly. What does `OnUIThread` do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need refresh data in ListBox control in WPF app so I must refresh data on UI thread, because WPF impelements STA model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Action<>` type, which encapsulates a method taking a parameter, or if you need a return value, the `Func` and `Func<>` types. For example:

```
static void PrintHello()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
}

static void PrintMessage(string message)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello " + message);
}

....
Action hello = new Action(PrintHello);
Action<string> message = new Action<string>(PrintMessage);

hello();
message("my world");
```

produces:

```
Hello world
Hello my world
```

Note how the action is created, just referencing the method that is encapsulated within, and then it's invoked, passing the required parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `Action`, but `Action<>`:

```
new System.Action<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, UserInfo>>>(RefreshContactsData).BeginInvoke(freshFriends, null, null);
```